# access main struct from packages

Tags: go

Please consider this sample go code, also here: https://play.golang.org/p/ZcNy_crAg51

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "play.ground/foo"
)

type SampleStruct struct {
    token int
}

var (
    MainSampleVar = SampleStruct{token: 333}
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello!")
    b := foo.Auxstruct{AuxToken: 4333}
    fmt.Printf("b: %#v\n", b)
    foo.AuxHello()
}
-- go.mod --
module play.ground
-- foo/foo.go --
package foo

import "fmt"

type Auxstruct struct {
    AuxToken int
}

func AuxHello() {
    fmt.Println("Aux says hello!")
}
```

I am able to access `foo.Auxstruct` in main.go.

Is it possible to go the other direction and access `main.SampleStruct` in package `foo`?

Please show how / explain.

Comment: No, because circular dependencies are not allowed.

Comment: in addition to previous comment i advise you to read this article https://golang.org/ref/mem

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Go because it would result in a circular dependency: `play.ground` imports `play.ground/foo` and `play.ground/foo` imports `play.ground`. Go doesn't allow such circular dependencies because they have [many disadvantages](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references).

There are several possible solutions:

1. You could move `SampleStruct` into the `play.ground/foo` package. This way you can use `SampleStruct` in `play.ground/foo` and import it into `play.ground`.
2. Alternatively, move `SampleStruct` into its own package, for example `play.ground/bar`. This way you can import `play.ground/bar` into both `play.ground/foo` and `play.ground`.